# How to get dynamic dns entry for ipv6-only host?

Tags: ipv6, dynamic-dns, dynamic-ip

The host is behind NAT and uses Teredo to get globally routable.

How to make it easily-reachable? For IPv4 case we just use no-ip or dyndns, however for ipv6 I don't see AAAA replies from dyndns's nameserver even though I specified "IPv6 Address (optional)":

```
$ dig vi.dyndns.org @ns1.dyndns.org | grep -v '^;'
vi.dyndns.org.          60      IN      A       1.2.3.4
...
ns1.dyndns.org.         60      IN      A       204.13.248.75
ns1.dyndns.org.         60      IN      AAAA    2600:2001::75
...

(I was expecting to get):
vi.dyndns.org.          60      IN      A       1.2.3.4
vi.dyndns.org.          60      IN      AAAA    2001:0:53aa:64c:c5b:4f1e:a9c6:61b1
...
```

How to make my host known in IPv6 world? Are there services like dyndns or no-ip, but for ipv6?

Comment: You shouldn't use Teredo for services.  You really should use that as last resort, for clients.

But yes, if the service supports IPv6, it usually have a parameter for setting IPv4 or IPv6 address.  And if you want to have different auto-selected, they usually uses two different URL:s.

And yes, there are other tunneling services. I uses HE services in https://tunnelbroker.net/, there are others. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both dyndns and, for example, freedns work, but your testing method is invalid. You should specify that you want AAAA entry in the DNS request:

```
$ dig -t AAAA vi.dyndns.org | egrep -v '^$|^;'
vi.dyndns.org.      172680  IN  AAAA    2001:0:53aa:64c:c5b:4f1e:a9c6:61b1

$ dig -t AAAA vi0oss.twilightparadox.com  | egrep -v '^$|^;'
vi0oss.twilightparadox.com. 172572 IN   AAAA    2001:0:53aa:64c:c5b:4f1e:a9c6:61b1
```

In order to dynamically update dyndns entries you can use [inadyn](http://www.inatech.eu/inadyn/inadyn.v1.96.zip) program:

```
inadyn-mt --ip_server_name www.whatismyv6.com -u vi0oss -p ********** -a vi.dyndns.org ip6
```

It gets address using public "show me my IP" sites, so you should add ipv6 entry of that site to your /etc/hosts it it fails out of the box.

Comment: Don't forget to select this answer as correct when you can, if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, DynDns doesn't allow dynamic update of IPv6 addresses. This makes DynDns unusable for me. I am behind a NAT (and I am refused port forwarding), so the only way to get my server online is teredo, but teredo keeps on changing my IPv6 address all the time.

Comment: Really? For me it works (although it took some time to find the right software). I'll update the answer to describe it.